# myuserform.show throws error 459 Object or Class does not support the set of events

Tags: excel, vba, patch, userform

Something has degraded.  Excel 2010 app put into service August 2014 broke after Microsoft's December 2014 patches.  Problem with ActiveX on worksheet "Cannot insert object" was fixed by deleting stale cache `C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd`.  Then second problem appeared.

> "Run-time error '459': Object or Class does not support the set of
>   events"

flags a `userform` name on my switchboard `userform`:

```
Private Sub btnAddViewEdit_Click()        
   frmAddViewEdit.Show        
End Sub
```

Has anyone else been patched upside the head lately?

Comment: Did you also clear this cache `C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\VBE\MSForms.exd`? I'm not sure if that will solve your problem, but it can't hurt.

Comment: I later cleared the VBE\MSForms.exd file, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I had corrupted my MSOffice installations.  MS recommends you run only one version of Office, but if you do install multiple, they recommend you install/repair/patch IN ORDER.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784668 .  I had removed 2003 and 2007, as well as 'repaired' (Programs and Features, Office, Change, Repair) 2010 and 2013 out of order.

The solution for my machine was to 'repair' 2010 and 2013 IN ORDER, then remove that pesky cache file at C:\Users[user.name]\AppData\Local\Temp\Excel8.0\MSForms.exd.

My users were impacted only by the first part of my patch problem, and were fixed by deleting their MSForms.exd file.